# Error in custom option file upload on magento 2.3.x

Tags: magento2.3, custom-options, image-upload

A few weeks ago some clients were uploading pdf files, and when they added to the cart, showed them an error the file is invalid,this is a lie, because it was upload a file with pdf extension.

here a one image show the js file
[image]

and this is the error what magento show me
[image]

so what i do for fix this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the issue discussed [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23518)... This is not you, it's the MSP_ReCaptcha module. The two possible fixes are 1) disable the two modules Paypal_ReCaptcha and MSP_Recaptcha if you don't use them, or 2) Overwrite the file in your theme.

Create a file in your theme at `app/design/<vendor>/<theme>/MSP_ReCaptcha/web/js/reCaptcha.js`

Copy over the contents from `vendor/msp/recaptcha/view/frontend/web/js/reCaptcha.js`

Change line 70 so it reads
`((this.settings) && (this.settings.lang)  ? '&hl=' + this.settings.lang : '&hl=en');`